# Как, используя PhoneGap/Cordova, сделать Android виджет?

Tags: android, phonegap

Возможно ли с помощью PhoneGap хоть как-нибудь создать виджет для Android?

Comment: В ходе работы с ним не видел такой возможности, но пишут, что реализовать можно, правда придется очень много своего кода писать, т.е. свои плагины делать для приложения.

Comment: Поищите Яндексе и Гугле по запросу: *С помощью PhoneGap создать виджет для Android*. Если я не поленился и нашел, думаю тебе тоже повезет, ведь там есть десятки сайтов, на которых есть описание как это можно сделать. Как говорят кто ищет, тот всегда находит.

Comment: да фуфло все эти ссылки, WebView в виджете нельзя использовать, если только собственный лаунчер написать

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, как-то и можно с фонгапом запуститься, но это будет "каша из топора".
Есть ограничение на контролы андроидовские, которые можно использовать в виджете
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout
И среди них нет WebView, а ведь идея фонгапа как раз в том, чтобы html+js в браузеро-подобном компоненте запускать.